# How to get max of a slice of a dataframe based on column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to make a new column, `MaxPriceBetweenEntries` based on the max() of a slice of the dataframe

```
idx Price EntryBar ExitBar
0   10.00 0        1
1   11.00 NaN      NaN
2   10.15 2        4
3   12.14 NaN      NaN
4   10.30 NaN      NaN
```

turned into

```
idx Price EntryBar ExitBar MaxPriceBetweenEntries
0   10.00 0        1       11.00
1   11.00 NaN      NaN     NaN
2   10.15 2        4       12.14
3   12.14 NaN      NaN     NaN
4   10.30 NaN      NaN     NaN
```

I can get all the rows with an EntryBar or ExitBar value with `df.loc[df["EntryBar"].notnull()]` and `df.loc[df["ExitBar"].notnull()]`, but I can't use that to set a new column:

```
df.loc[df["EntryBar"].notnull(),"MaxPriceBetweenEntries"] = df.loc[df["EntryBar"]:df["ExitBar"]]["Price"].max()
```

but that's effectively a guess at this point, because nothing I'm trying works. Ideally the solution wouldn't involve a loop directly because there may be millions of rows.

Comment: Why is your Price column different between your two samples?

Comment: @Chris Sorry about that, it was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forward fill the null values, group by entry and get the max of that groups Price.  Use that as the right side of a left join and you should be in business.

```
df.merge(df.ffill().groupby('EntryBar')['Price'].max().reset_index(name='MaxPriceBetweenEntries'), 
                                                                   on='EntryBar', 
                                                                   how='left')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can groupby the cumulative sum of non-null entries and take the max, unsing `np.where()` to only apply to non-null rows::

```
df['MaxPriceBetweenEntries'] = np.where(df['EntryBar'].notnull(),
                                        df.groupby(df['EntryBar'].notnull().cumsum())['Price'].transform('max'),
                                        np.nan)
df
Out[1]: 
   idx  Price  EntryBar  ExitBar  MaxPriceBetweenEntries
0    0  10.00       0.0      1.0                   11.00
1    1  11.00       NaN      NaN                     NaN
2    2  10.15       2.0      4.0                   12.14
3    3  12.14       NaN      NaN                     NaN
4    4  10.30       NaN      NaN                     NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try `groupby()` and `where`:

```
s = df['EntryBar'].notna()
df['MaxPriceBetweenEntries'] = df.groupby(s.cumsum())['Price'].transform('max').where(s)
```

Output:

```
   idx  Price  EntryBar  ExitBar  MaxPriceBetweenEntries
0    0  10.00       0.0      1.0                   11.00
1    1  11.00       NaN      NaN                     NaN
2    2  10.15       2.0      4.0                   12.14
3    3  12.14       NaN      NaN                     NaN
4    4  10.30       NaN      NaN                     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df.loc[df['ExitBar'].notna(),'Max']=df.groupby(df['ExitBar'].ffill()).Price.max().values
df
Out[74]: 
   idx  Price  EntryBar  ExitBar    Max
0    0  10.00       0.0      1.0  11.00
1    1  11.00       NaN      NaN    NaN
2    2  10.15       2.0      4.0  12.14
3    3  12.14       NaN      NaN    NaN
4    4  10.30       NaN      NaN    NaN
```